# Firefox 13.0.1 cannot correctly determine content type of docx file

Tags: .net, file-upload, cross-browser, mime-types

My MVC-3 application has a file upload feature. The file content and content type are saved in database so that while trying to download, the correct file can be reencrypted.

Everything is working fine except that if the browser is Firefox 13 (13.0.1 I have), the content type of `docx` file is detected as `text/plain` instead of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

I have checked that it works fine in IE. And now I am upgraded to Firefox 14.0.1. Its working fine too.

Now the question is, how can I determine the content type of a `HttpPostedFileBase` independent of browser?

Comment: @DannyG: No. Just Development Server provided by VS (2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original Answer

As I understand it, MIME types are not the most reliable thing.

Personally I would ignore the browser-provided content type completely, and use server map based on `FileName` extension (not precise either, but at least similar to the experience in OS itself).

After all, client can send you pretty much anything at all as a content type (dependning on the browser and, potentially, system).

#### Mapping extensions to Content Types

One option (as used by the question author) is to use entries in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`:

```
var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension, false);
var value = key != null ? key.GetValue("Content Type", null) : null;
var mime = value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: "use server map based on FileName extension"-- Well, is that reliable at all? What if someone has named a text file as `something.txt`? +1 for the idea.

Comment: It is not reliable, but if person renamed `x.xlsx` to `x.wtf`, it will not work in his (Windows) system, so he shouldn't expect that file download will open it with Excel. He can still download it as `application/x-wtf` (if server allows), then rename.

Comment: But the problem is, I do not save the file on disk. I save the file content and its type in database and reencode the file when someone wants to download. So, without the correct type, can I do that?

Comment: Why not? Unless you actually parse it, one set of file bytes is pretty much the same as any other set of file bytes. The type is only an annotation that is important to preserve to give a consistent experience. Or do you actually process file based on its type?

Comment: I do nothing by my self. I just do a `return File(content, type, downloadFileName);` Let me test what  happens when done as you said. I will let you know.

Comment: I have solved as you suggested and added the code in your answer. Please review it so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: Updated the answer (btw could not approve it as I did not see the change until site-wide reviewers already rejected it).

Answer (score 0):

The web development server may be your issue.  You might want to consider testing the solution on IIS and add the mime type to the configuration.  The alternative is to override the HTTP response header in the MVC application based off the file extension.

Comment: Why do you think its a development server issue? You had something like that before? I did not understand the Response header thing.

Comment: Are you using a controller action?